# optional fields in django models

Tags: django, model

I have the following model in django.

```
class Link(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    url = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    tag = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

I need the url field to be optional. How do I do this?

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Add the attribute [`blank=True`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#blank). Optionally, you can also make the field NULLable with [`null=True`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#null).

Answer (score 49):

Setting `null=True` for `CharField` is not recommended, as you can see from django docs:

> Avoid using null on string-based fields such as CharField and TextField. If a string-based field has null=True, that means it has two possible values for “no data”: NULL, and the empty string. In most cases, it’s redundant to have two possible values for “no data;” the Django convention is to use the empty string, not NULL. One exception is when a CharField has both unique=True and blank=True set. In this situation, null=True is required to avoid unique constraint violations when saving multiple objects with blank values.

So I would recommend this configuration:

`name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, default='')`

Comment: Good point. Thanks.